# Who is Bhikkhu Sīlācāra?

Tags: books

> ... The architect Rutch from Breslau had already designed a monastery with huts for monks, and the plan was that Bhikkhu Sīlācāra and other disciples were to join Nyanatiloka there. ...

(Wikipedia entry on Nyanatiloka)

Who is the monk mentioned above? What is the contribution that he has made? Any books by him?

Comment: There's a Wikipedia article with a list of his writings: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C4%ABl%C4%81c%C4%81ra

Comment: I edited the Wiki article so there is proper link to the above page. Thanks for sharing the information.

Answer (score 1):

The link lists a summary of Bhikkhu Silacara's life and other books about him.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C4%ABl%C4%81c%C4%81ra

It is a starting place to begin your study.

Comment: This is the same link as was posted by ChrisW on Sep 26th. Please avoid posting link answers. The question should be addressed in the answer itself.